# Android fragment -- OnDestroy being called when switching to a different tab followed by OnCreate when returning to the tab?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, mono, xamarin.android

I have a tabbed Android app.  When I switch away from a tab, I am seeing OnDestroy called for the corresponding fragment.  When I come back to that tab, I am then seeing OnCreate called for THE SAME FRAGMENT OBJECT.  It is definitely the same object, not another instance of the same class.  If I switch away to another tab, OnDestroy is called again, followed by a third call to OnCreate if I return to that tab, and so on.

Android [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) appear to state that this should not happen.

Does this indicate an architectural problem with my app?  If it's relevant, I am using Mono, and I am setting RetainInstance to true in OnActivityCreated.

EDIT: code below is from the activity that wraps all the tabs.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
  base.OnCreate(bundle);
  MainContext mainContext = MainContext;
  TabContext tabContext = mainContext.TabContext;
  // Tab is a custom model object; not related to Android tabs.
  List<Tab> tabs = tabContext.Tabs;
  foreach (Tab tab in tabs) {
    string displayString = tab.DisplayString;
    string withUnderscores = displayString.Replace(' ', '_');
    Type fragmentType = Type.GetType(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + "." + withUnderscores + "Fragment");
    this.AddTab(tab, (Fragment) Activator.CreateInstance(fragmentType));
  }
  ActionBar bar = this.ActionBar;
  bar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
  bar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
  bar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainTabActivityLayout);

  if (bundle != null) {
    int index = bundle.GetInt("index");
    ActionBar.SetSelectedNavigationItem(index);
  }
}

private void AddTab(Tab tab, Fragment fragment) {
  ActionBar bar = this.ActionBar;
  Android.App.ActionBar.Tab droidTab = bar.NewTab();


  droidTab.SetTag(tab.ToString());
  // omitting code that sets icon and display text.
  droidTab.TabSelected += (sender, e) => {
    e.FragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, fragment, tab.ToString());
  };

  this.ActionBar.AddTab(droidTab);
}
```

Comment: can you post some code where the switching of tab occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is calling the `onDestroy` because you are replacing the fragment each time you change the tab

```
e.FragmentTransaction.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, fragment, tab.ToString());
```

As you could see that you are only using one layout(`Resource.Id.fragmentContainer`) for replacing the fragment therefore it is reusing it after you change tab and releasing the memory of the replaced fragment thus calling the `onDestroy`.

Comment: @WilliamJockusch Android's architecture is, is... nm